# Give DROP PROCEDURE a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SqlServer for the first time, and in every single one of our create procedure scripts there is a block of code like below to remove the procedure if it already exists:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM information_schema.routines
           WHERE routine_name = 'SomeProcedureName'
           AND routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'

BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE SomeProcedureName
END
//then the procedure definition
```

To stop cutting and pasting this boilerplate code in every file I would like to put this code in its own stored procedure so that instead the scripts would look like this:

```
DropIfRequired('SomeProcedureName')
//then the procedure definition
```

My attempt at a solution is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropIfRequired
(
    @procedureName varchar
)
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines 
           WHERE routine_name = @procedureName 
           AND routine_type = 'PROCEDURE') 
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE @procedureName
END
```

But I then get the following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeleteProcedure, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '@procedureName'.

Any ideas how to do what I want?

Comment: This [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47186/16776) for more solutions to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full answer is:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @SQL = 'USE ' + DB_NAME() + CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @procName
--PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The one given by Andrew will only work if the default database for your login is set to the database you want.  When using dynamic sql you get a new database context.  So if you do not have a default database set you will execute the command from master.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I have been burned by that oversight before.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note is that in the DropIfRequired procedure, you have defined the procedure name as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropIfRequired
(    
   @procedureName varchar
)
```

You need to define a length of the varchar parameter, otherwise SQL will assume a length of one character. Instead, do something like as follows (1000 should be more than enough for most procedure names)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropIfRequired
(    
   @procedureName varchar(1000)
)
```

Comment: You could also use the datatype sysname (equivalent of nvarchar(128)), which would accomodate any valid object name.

Comment: "1000 should be more than enough for *most* procedure names"...I shudder to think of the exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

its missing quotes, try adding them in with an exec statement.

```
EXEC( 'DROP PROCEDURE ''' + @procName + '''') ( all single quotes)
```

Comment: Maybe better `exec('DROP PROCEDURE [' + @procName + ']')`